# WinXP Event Viewer: Internet Explorer - how to log events?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I'm trying to debug a strange rendering/interaction issue with a web application in IE and thought I'd peek at the event viewer in Windows (XP) to see if anything odd was happening at the same time.

I see categories for **System**, **Security**, **Application** etc. but I also see one for "***Internet Explorer***", but there are no events, and if I view the properties, I can't set a log file name... (thus I presume I can't log events)

Is there a magic setting somewhere in IE to allow this to work? Or is this category auto-generated by some other application and it just isn't hooked up properly?

PS The strange issue (for the curious) is that a popup window in a web app very randomly, on only one client site, after extended use, all of a sudden renders/paints completely black.  The HTML source is still there, and isn't set to <body bgcolor="#000000;...> but any interaction with the popup fails and IE needs to be completely restarted in order to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

What CodeByMoonlight provided will give you event viewer results for IE compatibility issues, but my understanding (I could be wrong) is that the full **[Application compatibility toolkit (ACT version 5.5)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=24da89e9-b581-47b0-b45e-492dd6da2971&displaylang=en)** will provide you with more debug/test tools to find the issue.  Might want to give it a try... there's some documentation here:  [**Internet Explorer 7 'Tips and Tricks'**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/thankyou.aspx?familyId=b1a24beb-c44f-40d6-825b-e571aa5973c0&displayLang=en)

Furthermore, you might want to take look at the gains from installing the [**Internet Explorer developer toolbar**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).

Comment: Oddly enough, I did install the ACT... but had difficulty getting it to report anything useful. (though I'll try again now that I remember it).

The IE Developer Toolbar is something I'm quite familiar with.  It isn't anywhere near as robust as Firebug or Fiddler, but in my case I think the odd issue being observed is at a lower level in the stack than the HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

That category was added to the Event Viewer with the installation of Internet Explorer 7.

It is empty because by default it is not told to log them, a setting called Application Compatibility Logging is off for IE.

If you want to turn it on for some reason, follow the instructions mentioned [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/spywaresucks/archive/2007/01/21/508759.aspx)